# What's the difference between max and maxBy in the KeyedStream

Tags: apache-flink

1. KeyedStream#max(String field)

> Applies an aggregation that gives the current maximum of the data
>   stream at the given field expression by the given key. An independent
>   aggregate is kept per key. A field expression is either the name of a
>   public field or a getter method with parentheses of the {@link
>   DataStream}'s underlying type. A dot can be used to drill down into
>   objects, as in {@code "field1.fieldxy" }.

2. KeyedStream#maxBy(String field)

> Applies an aggregation that gives the current element with the maximum
>   value at the given position by the given key. An independent aggregate
>   is kept per key. If more elements have the maximum value at the given
>   position, the operator returns the first one by default.

The javadoc for these two API looks very similar, I would ask what's the difference between them, and when to choose this one or that one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [difference](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/) between max and maxBy is that max returns the maximum value, whereas maxBy returns the element that has the maximum value in this field.

```
 keyedStream.max(0);
 keyedStream.max("key");
 keyedStream.maxBy(0);
 keyedStream.maxBy("key");
```

In the following examples, we can also see the difference:

Using [`max`](https://bytefish.de/blog/stream_data_processing_flink/):

```
  // Create a Tumbling Window with the values of 1 day:
            .timeWindow(Time.of(1, TimeUnit.DAYS))
            // Use the max Temperature of the day:
            .max("temperature")
            // And perform an Identity map, because we want to write all values of this day to the Database:
            .map(new MapFunction<elastic.model.LocalWeatherData, elastic.model.LocalWeatherData>() {
                @Override
                public elastic.model.LocalWeatherData map(elastic.model.LocalWeatherData localWeatherData) throws Exception {
                    return localWeatherData;
                }
            });
```

Using [`maxBy`](https://bytefish.de/blog/apache_flink_series_3/):

```
  // Now take the Maximum Temperature per day from the KeyedStream:
    DataStream<LocalWeatherData> maxTemperaturePerDay =
            localWeatherDataByStation
                    // Use non-overlapping tumbling window with 1 day length:
                    .timeWindow(Time.days(1))
                    // And use the maximum temperature:
                    .maxBy("temperature");
```

Comment: Thanks @TiMr for the helpful answer

Answer (score 1):

I can't also tell you the differences until I looked into the detailed implementations.

Let's assuem that the schema of your POJO record is (a: String, b: String, c: String).

> max(String field)

keyedStream.maxBy("a"), for each key, returns the first record whose field "a" is replaced with the max "a" of each key.

> maxBy(String field)

keyedStream.max("a") returns the record(get the first one if there are multiple records) with the max field "a".

For more information, you can check the [ComparableAggregator.java](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/aggregation).

Comment: Thanks @bupt_ljy for the helpful answer